# How can I increase the rate at which the 'fetch bounce' job works

Tags: civimail, bounce

The scenario is that bounces weren't being fetched and there is now a major backlog, and that running 50 every cron is too slow to make real progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach - modify /civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php

so it has multiple iterations specified (in example below = 40) then run via

drush cvapi Job.fetch_bounces

around line 178

`// process fifty at a time, CRM-4002
    $iterations = 0;
    while ($iterations < 40 && $mails = $store->fetchNext(MAIL_BATCH_SIZE)) {
      $iterations++;
      print("\nBeginning iteration $iterations ");
      foreach ($mails as $key => $mail) {
        print(".");`